# Give UI control Click event by code

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I want to do somethink like this:

```
<Grid Button.Click="grid_Button_Click">...</Grid>
```

but in code.
I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx, but I didn't found answer.

For example I have code:

```
Object gr = new FrameworkElement();
gr.Click = += ( o, args ) => { /* ... */ };
```

How to do it?

**EDITED**

Comment: Why do you want to set it programmatically? Is it that the event needs to be added at run-time after some other things have happened?

Comment: Are you trying to get when the user clicks anywhere on the `Grid` or in a row or cell or what? They each have a slightly different solution.

Comment: I want to do this to control with any type. Actually I dont know type of control because it is a Object type. I know only that it will be UI Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this, although I would debate the need.

Either way, it can be done like this...

```
Grid g = new Grid();
g.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, args) =>
       {
          //do stuff, you can reference s and args where s is the sender
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a handler to an attached event, call the `Add*Handler` method:

```
Class.AddSomeHandler(grid, (o, args) => ...);
```

`Button.Click` is not an attached event, so this method does not exist.

Comment: So what can I use instead of this?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  It's not an attached event.

Comment: It there any list of attached events? Do you have any link to list ot attached events?